# XCode error "Memory" with Z puzzle piece image?

Tags: c++, xcode, memory, plugins, compiler-errors

As I work to rescue an old project from software rot, I thought I had gotten rid of all my errors and straightened out all my link paths. Then appeared this doozy:

[image: error screen]

The category designation, Memory, I have never seen before. the puzzle piece with the Golden Z image I have never seen before.  That's all it will show, no code associated with the error. I'm guessing it's some sort of Xcode plug-in, but I'm not aware of having installed any. And furthermore the text reported in the error, e.g. "Joy", occurs nowhere in my source files.

Does anybody have the faintest idea where this error comes from?

XCode 4.6.3, MacOS 10.7.5
(Yes, I know this environment is as old as the hills, but this program depends upon Carbon and I really wish I could get it running one more time.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was at least a strange as the question.

1. I had put into the include paths the directory for a library that I myself created, RECURSIVELY.
2. In this directory I had left behind a TRULY ANCIENT tool from Apple called "carbon dater" that was useful to assist in conversion from pre-Carbon to Carbon programming!
3. In its subdirectories was a binary plug-in called Memory
4. This was getting found when looking for the standard C++ include file < Memory >

I found this by doing a Preprocess on my main C++ file, and found in there the following binary mess, including the word Joy:

Joy!peffpwpc∞›Zºˇˇˇˇp0p0p0```` ˇˇˇˇ¡Ω
vêˇˇˇˇ“ÄˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇˇO∞‹º7$1BW_ltÜîßµ¡Ã€Î˘*9IYdoÅêú§≤∫ƒÃ‘·Î˘)3ALX_jxÉèûßµ¡À‘€Â˛%1>EPals~áêö®Æ∫∆J```J ````J`````` J8BC````` ``````

Should I laugh or cry?